# Scala: to have all instances of the main

Tags: scala

there is a way in Scala to have all instances created in the main.

For example, I have the following classes: author, page, book.
In the main I create instances of these three classes.
In an instance of Book I put the writer and pages.

Then I want to check to see if there are pages that do not belong to any book.

The example is only explanatory, you do not give them too much importance.

Thank you all.
Sorry for the bad English translation.

Comment: Can you clarify the question? What is 'main', you mean your main application object? What makes you think you cannot create instances of classes in its body?

Comment: Yes, I meant the main object application, where it begins the execution of the program.
I know that you can create instances in his body. I want to keep track of all the instances that are created in the main method.

Excuse me for bad English translation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can

```
// If you use the REPL, :paste both class and object together
class Page {
  Page.everything += this
  var booked: Option[Book] = None   // Or just set to null
}
object Page {
  val everything: collection.mutable.HashSet[Page] = collection.mutable.HashSet()
}

class Book {
  var pages: Vector[Page] = Vector()
  def addPage(p: Page) { p.booked = Some(this); pages = pages :+ p }
}

// Create all your books and pages and assign them all

Page.everything.filter(_.booked.isEmpty)   // This contains all unassigned pages
```

to keep track for yourself.  (This is assuming single-threaded code; at your level of expertise, it's probably not worth worrying about how to do this in parallel.)

Alternatively, if you want to make sure everything happens in the `main` method, you can do something like

```
// File Page.scala
class Page(text: String)(implicit mhm: MustHaveMe) {
}

// File Main.scala
object Main {
  sealed trait MustHaveMe
  private final object YesYouHaveMe extends MustHaveMe
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    implicit val okayHere = YesYouHaveMe
    new Page("Once upon a time")
  }
}
```

Now, access restrictions will prevent anyone but `Main.scala` from creating a new page, and only the `main` method within the `Main.scala` file will have the implicit needed to create a `Page`.  Thus, you can make it easier to avoid creation of objects elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: no, there is no fully automated way to do this. You would need to iterate over all allocated objects, which is something the garbage collector can do, but the program itself cannot.

What follows is a sketch of **one** possible way of keeping track which sub-objects have been attached to root objects.

Define basic traits that allow us to distinguish between sub- and root objects:

```
trait Root

trait Sub {
  def register(r: Root)
  def deregister(r: Root)
  def isRegistered: Boolean
}
```

Then we define a root object `Book` to which we can add pages:

```
class Book(val title: String) extends Root {
  private var pages: Set[Page] = Set()

  Books.books += this

  def add(p: Page) {
    pages += p
    p.register(this)
  }

  def remove(p: Page) {
    pages -= p
    p.deregister(this)
  }
}
```

On instantiation, each book adds itself to a global repository:

```
object Books {
  var books: Set[Book] = Set()
}
```

Likewise for the sub-object `Page`:

```
class Page(number: Int) extends Sub {
  private var owner: Option[Root] = None

  Pages.pages += this

  def register(r: Root) = owner match {
    case None =>
      owner = Some(r)
    case Some(o) =>
      sys.error("%s is already owned by %s, thus it cannot be owned by %s"
                .format(this, o, r))
  }

  def deregister(r: Root) = owner match {
    case Some(s) if r == s =>
      owner = None
    case Some(s) =>
      sys.error("%s is owned by %s, but not by %s"
                .format(this, s, r))
    case None =>
      sys.error("%s is not owned at all, thus also not by %s"
                .format(this, r))
  }

  def isRegistered = owner.nonEmpty
}

object Pages {
  var pages: Set[Page] = Set()

  def allRegistered = pages.forall(_.isRegistered)
}
```

Some usage examples:

```
val p1 = new Page(1)
val p2 = new Page(2)
val p3 = new Page(3)

val b1 = new Book("Fahrenheit 451")
val b2 = new Book("Brave New World")

b1.add(p1)
b1.add(p2)
b2.add(p3)

println(Pages.allRegistered) // true

val p4 = new Page(4)

println(Pages.allRegistered) // false

b2.add(p4)
b2.remove(p3)

println(Pages.allRegistered) // false

b2.add(p1) // Exception: already owned
```

**Note:** Design decisions to keep in mind, open questions:

- How to proceed if a sub-object is to be destroyed? Remove it from the global repository?
- Can a sub-object be owned by multiple root objects?
- Would it be better to have multiple, non-global repositories? That probably means we need factories to create and register sub-objects.
- In a concurrent setting we have to synchronise access to the (global) repositories
- Can we move the code for (de)registering sub-objects into a single trait and then reuse it in every root object?

**Note II:** If we had backpointers we would only need a (global) sub-object repository. However, I am not aware of any language that offers built-in backpointers.

Answer (score 1):

No, you'll have to keep track of them yourself. Don't think any language really does this. Of course, you can write your classes in such a way that they do this, but it's your responsibility.

Answer (score 0):

I have to be able to create independently my pages and books
The thing that interests me is to keep track of all instances created.
As you have suggested, I think I deploy my class book as well:

```
class Book(var name: String, var pages: List[Page]){
AllBook.allbook += this
}

object AllBook {
var allbook: Set[Book] = Set()
}
```

In a similar way also the class Page.
As the last instruction in the main method, use a method call "validation" that must control my constraints.

This may be fine?
Is there a better solution?

Note: The constraints are independent respect the implementation of the classes

Excuse me for the bad English translation